# Can anyone explain .split(''); in Razor?

Tags: razor, split

I sitting here with a ton of code (that works) which I have to look through, and some of it happens to be in Razor. Not too hard to understand, yet not something I've tried before.

My problem is that the function .split(''); (notice the '') comes up several times and I don't understand neither the purpose nor what it does, cause I feel like it would just give an error to split on nothing.

I can't really test anything as the code is way too large for me to be able to just run to check such a minor thing, and there are no real places to test Razor unless I get enough understanding to just make a testpage from scratch.

The most simple example I can find is this:

```
    function openbysetting(settingcookie) 
    {
        var settingsarray = settingcookie.split('');
        for (var i = 0; i < settingsarray.length; i++) 
        {
            if (settingsarray[i] == 'f') 
            {
                ....
            }
        };
    }
```

Mind you, settingcookie isn't defined or mentioned anywhere else in this entire code, so I don't even understand why a regular split function would be required.
Edit: Never mind, I'm told it's a javascript thing. Just ignore the previous sentence.

As for a result, I'd expect it to just simply not work, but it seems to be doing fine.

C# just gives an error if you do it, and this is a C# based language after all.

Hope someone can clarify. Thank you.

Edit: Okay, I understand now. It just splits between every single character. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `openbysetting` is Javascript function defined in your Razor view. It is not C# nor it is something Razor cares about. It just outputs it as part of the view, to be executed in the browser.

Comment: I see... That's my bad, but what does the .split part of the code do?

Comment: It [splits it into characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - notice `settingsarray[i] == 'f'` which checks for the character `f`.

Comment: Hah, right as you said that, I actually figured out that it simply splits between every single character like you said. Turning "Hello world" into "H", "e", "l" and so on.

Thank you for the reply though. I'm not really that good at Razor, and it's hard to find much documentation on it, either because it's new, it's rare or I'm stupid.

Comment: I can recommend reading this [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c). :-)

Comment: That will be helpful. :o I wonder how I didn't find that page when searching around for tutorials.

Thank you so much ^^